# Extremely simple SQLite query doesn't return expected

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

Below I provide my database schema, the database data currently inserted (which is only one record), and the code I am running. It is a very simple setup, but instead of returning the one record in the database, it returns nothing. Anyone have any idea why? I am on my wit's end here...

**Table:** Subcontractor

**Columns:** listed below in (name type) format.

```
ID guid, 
BusinessName varchar(50), 
Address varchar(200), 
City varchar(50), 
State varchar(50), 
ZipCode varchar(50), 
Contact varchar(50), 
Phone varchar(50), 
Fax varchar(50), 
Email varchar(200), 
GLOPolicy bit, 
GLOLimit bigint, 
GLOExpiration datetime, 
ALPolicy bit, 
ALLimit bigint, 
ALExpiration datetime, 
WCPolicy bit, 
WCLimit bigint, 
WCExpiration datetime, 
ULPolicy bit, 
ULLimit bigint, 
ULExpiration datetime, 
Notes varchar(15000)
```

**=====**

**I have one record in my database, as follows.**

```
ID "7b143c19-ad66-46ad-b587-db0bee98cf1e"
BusinessName "1"
Address "1"
City "1"
State "1"
ZipCode "1"
Contact NULL
Phone NULL
Fax NULL 
Email NULL
GLOPolicy False (0) 
GLOLimit NULL 
GLOExpiration NULL
ALPolicy False (0)
ALLimit NULL
ALExpiration NULL
WCPolicy False (0)
WCLimit NULL
WCExpiration NULL
ULPolicy False (0) 
ULLimit NULL
ULExpiration NULL
Notes NULL
```

**=====**
**I am attempting the following query, and it returns nothing, when it should obviously return the only record, shown above.**

```
String ID = "7b143c19-ad66-46ad-b587-db0bee98cf1e";
DataTable dt = sqliteQuery.selectFromDatabase("*", "WHERE ID = '" + ID + "'");
```

**And the code for the above method is...**

```
    public DataTable selectFromDatabase(String column, String filter)
    {
        string SQL = "SELECT " + column + " FROM SUBCONTRACTOR " + filter;
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(SQL);
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            da.Fill(ds);
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: First try to select without filtering. Set your predicate to be WHERE 1 = 1 (always true) instead of the filter to make sure you get all the rows. If you don't then it's not the query at fault. Also, your column type is A GUID but your query uses a string value. You might need a conversion.

Comment: When setting the filter to 1=1, it returns the single record in the database, as it should. What type of conversion is there suppose to be? I was under the assumption everything was passed as strings when doing queries... is that not the case? If it isn't, do you know of such a conversion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like SqLite does not support a GUID type natively. It's supported by wrappers and plugins but I think that you're experiencing some impedance between the way the type is used. You are probably better off changing it to a TEXT type. Your predicate will then work.

**EDIT**

To create a new GUID value to insert into the row as a pkey just do:

```
Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

In addition I found [the following info](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/p/1546/6729.aspx):

> GUID is not(!) a native
>   SQLite-datatype, but an addon provided
>   by Robert's wrapper. In the connection
>   string you can specify
>   "BinaryGUID=Yes|No", with Yes as
>   default. When "BinaryGUID=Yes" the
>   GUID is stored taking 16 bytes of
>   storage. Now it depends whether
>   "SQLite Expert" recognises the
>   datatype GUID. If so, you should look
>   at its documentation how it is
>   handled. If not, it is probably
>   treated as text (likely with invalid
>   character data). You will have this
>   trouble again when you change your
>   SQLite editor or wrapper.
>
> When "BinaryGUID=No" the GUID is
>   stored as text taking 32-38 bytes (I
>   don't know whether the minus-signs and
>   braces {} are stored, you have to
>   test). When storage is not a large
>   problem, I would recommend to use this
>   form. You then should have no problems
>   with whatsover wrapper or DB editor
>   you use and save a lot of time and
>   trouble.

There seems to be an issue with the type itself.

Comment: So, the wrapper converts a hexadecimal? Blah, is there a way to easily do what I'm doing above in a way that will actually work? -_-

Comment: Yeah. Change your ID column type to text. (I made that the main point of my answer.)

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the text datatype, does it give a unique value for every record like guid does? Or would I have to do that manually somehow?

Comment: There are only a few data types and varchar(50) should do fine, meaning that it will work like Sqlite's TEXT type. (The wrappers really confuse things... Makes it look like Sql Server.) And yes, you will have to insert a GUID yourself but that is VERY EASY to do. It's actually a member of the GUID class.

Comment: See the EDIT for the GUID generating code. Very simple, static method call.

Comment: Yes, all GUIDs are guaranteed to be unique. And yes, Guid.NewGuid is how you create one. Wikipedia will have a great article but quickly: A GUID is a semi-randomly generated, 128 bit value (2^128) that is used to uniquely identify db records (and many other things.) The size of the GUID and the algorithm means that the chances for a collision (creating two identical GUIDs) are astronomically unlikely.

Comment: Paul, you've been extremely helpful. Thanks very much for dedicating the time to help me out. I've been hitting my head against the wall for a while on this one, so you've relieved a lot of stress. Cheers!

Comment: If this scares you in any way, don't let it. MS Sql Server replication depends on the GUID algorithm as do many other RDBMSs that do replication.

Comment: Sorry Paul, one more question. Given I'm using System.Guid, what would you recommend I set my guid to? Text or varchar?

Comment: Well that the interesting question. SqLite only has a Text type. Varchar is from Sql Server and the wrapper you're using. So it's actually both. The table in SqlLite will be Text and it will be varchar in your code. Does that make sense? Actually, here's a better explanation: http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg29794.html

Comment: CODe: Did you revoke the acceptance on the answer? Did something backfire? Btw, why are you using SqLite? There are many RDBMs to choose from.

Comment: @Paul: Weird, sorry about that, I'll mark it as the answer again... I am using SQLite by the way.